# Add Gift Messages in the Product Page

Tags: product

I want to Show up **`Add gift messages`** option in the product page.

Currently, this option is showing in checkout out, but I need this option in the product page itself.

If I use custom option, for many products this may be difficult, so I need the way to do this in programmatically.

Any Ideas?

Comment: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/magento/109-magento-sales-orders/disabling-or-enabling-gift-messages-on-products-in-magento refer this link

Comment: this shows Gift Messages option on checkout page. but I wants to show up it on product page itself.

Comment: Please use custom option....

Comment: For each products adding custom option be not good solution.

Comment: I do know about this extension that adds custom message in checkout, contact these Fme guys they can surely customize their script for you,
http://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/gift-wrap-extra-fee.html

Answer (score 2):

You can create a text type custom option for the product and simply call it gift message.

Also, make it optional so that users don't have to necessarily fill it.

To add the cost of gift wrapping - add two custom options -

1. Gift Wrap (Add amount if this one is selected)
2. Gift Message.

Comment: Use CSV Bulk Update if you don't want to manually add this custom option to each product.

Comment: how to do it programmatically not by manually